# Android Swipe Images Intro Screen on First Run

Tags: android, screen, swipe

I've been looking around a lot lately but haven't really found much on this.

I'm making my third Android app and **I'm looking to implement an intro screen on first run of the app where a series of images are shown explaining the apps functionality and the idea behind it; you can swipe the images left or right and at the last image you get to the app by swiping.**

I really like the sort of thing they have done with the **CamScanner** app but despite my searching I have no idea how to implement it other knowing a little bit about some people referring to Fragments. Any help would be appreciated greatly and since we need better UI on Android, a good answer would help a lot of developers take the cue! :)

Comment: I think,you just use viewpager for viewing with the screen as a page and after last page you just open your main screen.

Comment: @Nil.. That was really helpful! I think I'll add a guide here once I'm done with it! Also, any idea how to launch the main app activity on last slide while ensuring that the viewpager isn't active and using memory?

How would one go about displaying this viewpager just once on first start or on every update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a method to show popup window. show images in a scroll view in that popup. at last image set touch listener to dismiss that popup.
and call that method from onResume method of your Activity like this

```
protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(MyPrefs, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean b = pref.getBoolean("FirstTime",true);
        if(b)
        { new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                showIntroPopup();
            }
        }, 100);

        }
    }
```

in that popup set "FirstTime" boolean to false in SharedPreferences.

Comment: But the problem with this is that it will display the images in a pop-up, while fragments are a much more efficient and standardized way of doing it. Also, using a scroll view won't allow the images to swipe one at a time. :)

Comment: ViewPager should work fine here. http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html